# Ubuntu to have multiple clones on one external drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, backup, clone

I recently backed up my entire Ubuntu 64bit 14.04 operating system using Clonezilla onto an exteranl hard drive, and wish to make a second clone, as my system has been updated. I want to keep both backups on the same external drive, but am not sure if this will work, considering there are boot partitions and swap partitions included in the clones.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Quite seamless.

When you create a clone backup, the backup will store in a directory by a unique name.  The system will prompt you with the name to save it to of which you can modify the name.

The default name will have the date and time as part of the name.  You can append or prefix that default date and time name with specifics like full-backup-of-kids-computer.  For instance:

```
kids-computer-20160111
```

The name you specify will be a directory where the actual backup would be stored.

If you decide to do another backup of the same computer you can specify something unique such as:

```
kids-computer-20160111-B
```

**The basic cloning options**

With Clonezilla you will have two cloning options.  You can either clone `device to image` or `device to device`.  If you clone `device to device` (which is drive to drive) the target drive will become a clone of the source drive.

If you clone `device to image` you would have the options described above.  The source drive would be save to a folder on the destination drive.

Comment: James - thank you for taking the time to reply.  I have a question about  how these clones are stored. When I look at the first backup that I created (we will call this clone-A), I see 3 partitions, which include the boot partition,  the main partition where the /home folder is located, and the Linux swap. 
 If I were to clone the original drive again as Clone-B,  and place that on the same drive as Clone-A, would there not be 2  boot partitions , 2 /home folder partitions, and 2 Linux swap file partitions?

Comment: You see those files (the backup you're describing) in a folder.  If you perform a different backup the files that you see will be in a different folder.  You have described the components of a clone of a drive.  That clone is in  a folder.  You wouldn't be looking at the same folder if you performed a different backup.  You'd be looking at the similar filenames in different folder.

Comment: im confused, these arent folders im talking about, im referring to partitions that can be seen by Gparted. While I understand they may be stored in 'folders' somewhere, but when observed by Gparted or Clonezilla, they will be seen as partitions. SO I will ask again and clarify. If I were to clone the original drive again as Clone-B, and place that on the same drive as Clone-A, would there not be 2 boot partitions , 2 /home folder partitions, and 2 Linux swap file partitions? If this is the case, how does the BIOS differentiate between these partitions. ?

Comment: Where will you be saving (cloning) your partition to?  If you were cloning it to a drive you can only clone one drive to another.  The drive you are cloning to will be come an exact duplicate of the drive you are cloning from.  That is called cloning from device to device.  If you clone to an image you would have what I described in my answer.   The drive you are cloning from would have an image on the drive you are cloning to.  The image will be stored in a folder by the name you give it.  If you called it Clone-A, that would be the name of the folder that you would find on the target drive.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I updated my answer to clarify the cloning options.

Comment: thanks for the update, that explains things a bit better. Is it fairly easy to boot from an `image`, or does it have to be converted and installed before accessing it?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid You can't boot to a clonezilla image.  You would have to restore the  image to a media to use it.  There is a process, however for exporting a clonezilla to a disk image (a single img or iso file).  Take a look at: [How to mount a Clonezilla img to extract files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156653/how-to-mount-a-clonezilla-img-to-extract-files)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34183/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-kalamalka-kid).